# How to use a Cognito group to Perfom Administrator level task in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-amplify

I have succeeded in programatically adding a cognito user to a group in React. Now my problem is Any user from any group can do this but I only want users from the admin group to be capable od doing this. Yes I know I could simply place the method into classes only the admin group can access by routing basses on `accessTokens`. But I was wondering if I were to for example,  give the admin group the IAM-Role AdministratorAccess which technically should give that group access to everything how would I have to change my configuration in React so that this would work. Below is my code but this is the version that uses the accesskeyid and soon of the IAM user but as I said I would like to use the cognito group and not the IAM user. Hope my question is understandable. Thanks for the help.

```
 AWS.config.update({ credentials: {
  accessKeyId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    secretAccessKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",

},
region: 'xx-xx-xx'

});

 var params = {
  GroupName: 'TestGroup', 
  UserPoolId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 
  Username: 'testuser',

};

var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminAddUserToGroup(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log('bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb: ', err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Comment: You attach an admin role to the cognito group and then just log in with a user in that group. I don't understand what the problem is here.

Comment: even if I login with a user from another group, the user is also able to perform this action although it's only supposed to be the admin group

Comment: You have to to pass access key secret key and session id you get from cognito login to authenticate your requests. I'm guessing your requests are authenticated by default IAM role

Comment: Oh now I see. Yeah I used the default IAM role. Thanks alot.

Comment: sorry for disturbing again but how do I access these? Tried to log my user data but can't find it there

Comment: you get this by calling the getcredentialsforidentity method. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetCredentialsForIdentity.html

Comment: Hi @Ninad, I just used the getcredentials for identity method and it returned the access key and secret key but it didn't return the session id instead it gave me the sessionToken. So I tried editing the code in my question above and added the access key and secretkey but when I run the code I get a missing config in credentials error which I suppose is because of the lacking session id so please how can I access the sessionid. Thanks!

Comment: Just pass the session token in.

Comment: Tried that just now but it still returns the missing credentials error unfortunately